# Configurar jBoss para requisitar certificado digital do cliente

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss, ssl, certificado-digital

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web utilizando o jBoss EAP 6.1.

Como um dos requisitos, o sistema deverá realizar a autenticação do usuário via certificado digital. Para isso configurei devidamente o jBoss para rodar em `https://` utilizando o protocolo SSLv3, criei um certificado para o servidor e referenciei o certificado da CA e configurei `verify-client="false"`.

Depois no `web.xml` da minha aplicação, configurei para requisitar o certificado digital do cliente no `/LoginByCert`

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginByCert</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Depois disto ao acessar `https://localhost:443/MyApp/LoginByCert`, o jBoss lança o erro:

> Exception getting SSL attributes: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed

e o browser abre a carteira do cliente para escolher o certificado. Uma vez escolhido o certificado, o jBoss mostra no navegador:

> Status 401 - JBWEB000010: Cannot authenticate with the provided credentials

Alguém me poderia ajudar? Obrigado pelo seu tempo.